# Not able to shuffle the `ng-show` on click of `ng-repeat` element

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

on click of an element i am showing a list. as well on click on the same list element, I am hiding the list. but on click on the list element not hiding the parent.

here is the snippet. click on the show and click on the one of the list element.

```js
var app = angular.module('dropdown', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.names = ["one", "click and hide ", "three"]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="dropdown" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <span ng-click="show = !show">Show me</span>
    <ul ng-show="show">
      <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-click="show = !show">{{name}}</li> <!-- not hiding on click -->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

what is wrong here? how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-repeat makes a new scope. You need `$parent.show = !$parent.show`

```js
var app = angular.module('dropdown', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.names = ["one", "click and hide ", "three"]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="dropdown" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <span ng-click="show = !show">Show me</span>
    <ul ng-show="show">
      <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-click="$parent.show = !$parent.show;">{{name}}</li> <!-- not hiding on click -->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare as a function and call from any where. So you can you this:

```js
var app = angular.module('dropdown', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.names = ["one", "click and hide ", "three"];
  $scope.toggle = function(){
      $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="dropdown" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <span ng-click="toggle()">Show me</span>
    <ul ng-show="show">
      <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-click="toggle()">{{name}}</li> <!-- Now this is hiding on click -->
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="dropdown" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<span ng-click="show = !show">Show me</span>
<ul ng-show="show">
  <li ng-repeat="name in names" ng-click="$parent.show = !$parent.show">{{name}}</li> <!-- not hiding on click -->
</ul>
```

Does that work? You have to call the parent's scope :)